# trigger textarea change event without removing tinymce

Tags: javascript, tinymce, textarea

I am trying to update a textarea value without removing tinymce from it.

I need to trigger the change effect on the textarea to save the contents, but whenever I trigger the change event, the tinymce goes away and the textarea appears.

Comment: Without seeing any code nobody can really help you.  Perhaps you can make a TinyMCE Fiddle or JS Fiddle showing what you have done and what is happening?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve